# No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2 -- Yesterday same project worked

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I have opened up the project that I have not touched since yesterday.

Now, I am getting a typescript error for an object in a tsx component.

```js
<Shadowed {...getRootProps()} {...props} dropped={dropped} left={left} isDragActive={isDragActive} id='Drop zone'>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ?
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p>
          :
          !userHasntDropped ?
            <DropHere />
            :
            <FileCard file={dropped} isDragActive={isDragActive} selected={selected} />
      }
</Shadowed>
```

Dropped is a file I'm getting from the redux state:

```
const dropped: any = useSelector(state => left ? state.files.fileLeft : state.files.fileRight);
```

Shadowed is a styled-component:

```js
const Shadowed = styled.div`

  height:${props => props.dropped && props.dropped.length > 0 ? '100px' : 'calc(50% - 50px)'};
  width:${props => props.dropped && props.dropped.length > 0 ? '240px' : '25%'};
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  pointer-events: auto;
  align-self:${props => props.dropped && props.dropped.length > 0 ? 'flex-end' : 'center'};
  margin-bottom:25px;
  margin-top:25px;

  border:${props => props.dropped && props.dropped.length > 0 ? '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.20)' : 'null'};
  cursor:pointer;

  border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow:${props => props.dropped && props.dropped.length > 0 ? null : props.isDragActive ? '0px 0px 25px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)' : '4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), -4px -4px 16px 10px #fff'};
    background:${props => props.isDragActive ? 'white' : 'rgb(252, 253, 254)'};

  &:hover{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 25px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background:white;
  }
`
```

Error I am getting:

```
C:/Users/danie/Code/compare/src/compareapp/ui/DropIt.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/danie/Code/compare/src/compareapp/ui/DropIt.tsx(62,46):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; dropped: any; left: Boolean; isDragActive: boolean; refKey?: string; defaultChecked?: boolean; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[]; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean; ... 249 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: (event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
      Property 'dropped' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; dropped: any; left: Boolean; isDragActive: boolean; refKey?: string; defaultChecked?: boolean; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[]; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean; ... 249 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: (event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
      Property 'dropped' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.  TS2769

    60 | 
    61 |   return (
  > 62 |     <Shadowed {...getRootProps()} {...props} dropped={dropped} left={left} isDragActive={isDragActive}>
       |                                              ^
    63 |       <input {...getInputProps()} />
    64 |       {
    65 |         isDragActive ?
```

1. I've tried switching back to a previous typescript version but got the same error.
2. I've tried adding types to the initialstate of redux
3. I've tried if it is a styled-components error through this solution: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245#issuecomment-446011384

What could be going on here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added interface definitions to the styled components like this:

```
interface ShadowedProps {
  readonly isDragActive: boolean;
  readonly dropped: any;
};



const Shadowed = styled.div<ShadowedProps>`
  {*** CSS here ***}
`
```

Now it works. This is clearly documented on styled-components, here: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript

I was unaware that we have to do this explicitly. It is really odd that it worked so far, I have no idea what made it realise I am using it badly.